# Closing a modal window from parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, joomla, modal-dialog

I have a modal window which is loading an external HTML page. I am trying to figure out how to close this modal window after the content has been loaded. Since this is an external page I will not be able to change this content so I'm guessing that I need to put an event listener on the parent page that can detect when the modal window content has been loaded?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how are you loading the external modal window?  any existing code you can share?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `.load()` to load the external HTML page? If so, you can put a callback function in the `load()` function. Like this:

```
$('#someDiv').load(function(){
    //Put code to close the modal
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JS:

To call a method in the parent window from the modal:

```
window.opener.document.globalMethodInOpeningFile(param1, param2);
```

To close the modal window, call this once content is loaded (you can use `.load(callbackFn)` to check for load`):

```
window.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're opening this modal page with `window.showModalDialog()` then you can't. As its own name indicates, it opens a *modal* window. Execution of javascript in your main (opener) page will be suspended until the modal closes (because modal dialogs can return values, so the caller must wait for the dialog to close before continuing). As the page you're opening is an external page (I assume in another domain), the only way for it to close, is that the user closes it.

If this is not acceptable, then you need to use `window.open` or an HTML modal window like the ones jQuery UI offers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using Joomla's core modal feature.  Another assumption is the controlling logic is located inside the modal window.  Which is why the answer isn't as straight forward as it could be because I'm unsure of the workflow which opens the external HTML page you wish to fire the event after.  However, after the logic which opens the external HTML page has fired, you can use the following JavaScript embedded inside your modal window's rendered HTML to close the modal window:

```
window.parent.SqueezeBox.close();
```